# Percentage that each element appears in a vector

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to take a vector and return the percentage that each element appears.

See below for the input vector and the expected result.

```
InputVector<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)

ExpectedResult<-data.frame(Value=c(1,2,3), Percentile=c(0.5,0.3,0.2))
```

In this case, 1 appears `50%` of the time, 2 appears `30%` and 3 appears `20%` of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the frequency count with `table` on the vector, apply `proportions` to convert it to proportions, and then reshape the named vector to a two column `data.frame` with `stack` in `base R`

```
stack(proportions(table(InputVector)))[2:1]
```

-output

```
  ind values
1   1    0.5
2   2    0.3
3   3    0.2
```

---

Or use `tidyverse` to get the frequency `count` and apply `proportions` on the frequency column 'n' to get the `percentile`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(Value = InputVector) %>%
   count(Value) %>% 
   mutate(Percentile = proportions(n), n = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Value Percentile
  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1        0.5
2     2        0.3
3     3        0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

A little simpler, to get the proportions.

`table(InputVector) / length(InputVector)`